# unable to show p tags using this onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have little bit experience in Jquery,  Here i am trying to create a plugin of jquery, but i am stuck here, I am trying to show the p tag element
button was click,

```js
$(function() {
  var myFirst = {
    paragraph: $('p'),
    init: function() {
      $("<button></button>", {
          text: "My New Button"
        }).appendTo('.mybutton')
        .on('click', function() {
          $(this).find('p').show();
        });
    }
  }
  myFirst.init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mybutton"></div>

<p style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad illo nobis mollitia. Ex nemo quae vero, rem, magnam numquam repudiandae. Labore laborum officia corporis sint voluptatem est, odio quidem libero.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks for the p tag inside the button.

```
$(this).find('p').show();
```

try this

```
$('p').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your DOM traversal. The `p` is a sibling of the parent to the `button` you append, yet you're attempting to `find()` within the button. Use `parent().next('p')` instead:

```js
$(function() {
  var myFirst = {
    paragraph: $('p'),
    init: function() {
      $("<button></button>", {
        text: "My New Button"
      }).appendTo('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next('p').show();
      });
    }
  }
  myFirst.init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mybutton"></div>
<p style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad illo nobis mollitia. Ex nemo quae vero, rem, magnam numquam repudiandae. Labore laborum officia corporis sint voluptatem est, odio quidem libero.</p>
```

That being said, the logic here is too closely coupled to the structure of the HTML. I'd suggest creating all the relevant elements within your `init()` logic - however if this is just for testing you don't necessarily need to go that in depth.

Comment: I don't know what you mean - it works fine in the snippet. Also note that the other answer will show all the `p` tags on the page. That's fine for your example HTML but may cause issues in a working project